# What is the use of having a less restricted method in a more restricted class in java?

Tags: java, overriding

Eg

```
class Abc{
   public void fun() 
    {
      System.out.println("public method") ;
    }
    @Override
   public String toString() 
    {
      // "has to be public method but the access is default because of the class access";
      return super.toString();
    }
    
}
```

In the above Eg -  fun method  access is public but the class access is default hence what is the use of having the method public rather than default because it cannot be access without creating object.

In the same way the toString method has to be public since (overriding cannot restrict the access). But it is already getting restricted since the class access is default

My Basic question is
What is the use of having a less restricted method in a more restricted class?

Comment: this is not because it has use, this is because you are trying to override it. You can perfectly overload it, but then again, in many cases where you'll try to use the toString (for instance, in a System.out.print statement), it 'll use the public method.

Comment: Likewise, you might have a class which is package-private but implements a public interface, and some other public class has a factory for it. Or the package-private class might have a public subclass which inherits its public members.

Answer (score 6):

> My Basic question is What is the use of having a less restricted method in a more restricted class?

There are several purposes related to inheritance and polymorphism.  The biggest of those is probably that methods that override superclass methods or implement interface methods cannot be more restricted than the method they override.  In this regard, I note that you express a possible misconception when you say:

> the toString method has to be public since (overriding cannot restrict the access). But it is already getting restricted since the class access is default

That class `Abc` has default access does not prevent any other class from having references to instances of `Abc` or from invoking the public methods of that class.  The declared type of any such reference will be a supertype of class `Abc`, but the implementation invoked will be that provided by `Abc`.

Additionally, there is the question of signaling intent.  It is helpful to view the access specified for class members to be qualified by the access level of the class.  Thus, declaring `fun()` to be `public` says that it can be accessed by everyone *who can access an instance of `Abc`*.  This is somewhat useful in its own right, but it also turns out to be especially useful if the access level of the class is ever changed.  If the class's designer chose member access levels according to this principle, then those do not need to be revisited under these circumstances.

Comment: "The declared type of any such reference will be a supertype of class Abc" - could it not also be a subtype? If we consider an instance of a subclass to also be an instance of the class.

Comment: That would be a question of terminology @kaya3.  By "an instance of class Abc", I mean an object whose class is `Abc`, in which case no, the reference cannot have a subclass of `Abc` as its type.  But you are right that similar could apply to a reference whose type was a subtype of `Abc`.

Comment: This means by making class default we are only restricting the access of the reference to default and not the instance
We still can have a public construction and hence public instance of Abc?

Comment: @VinayakBansal, making class `Abc` default-access prevents classes outside the package from referencing it by name.  That includes preventing any class outside the package from instantiating an object of class `Abc` by use of the `new` operator, regardless of the access level of any constructors.  But a class inside the package can instantiate an `Abc` and then provide a reference to that object to objects of classes from other packages.

Answer (score 2):

On its face?

Absolutely no purpose whatsoever. It's measurable (you can use reflection to fetch a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object that represents that method, and you can ask it if it is public, and the answer would be 'yes', but it doesn't actually change how accessible that method is.

However, taking a step back and thinking about the task of programming in its appropriate light, which includes the idea that code is usually a living, breathing idea that is continually updated: Hey, your class is package private today. Maybe someone goes in and makes it public tomorrow, and you intended for this method to be just as public as the type itself if ever that happens.

Specifically in this case, you're overriding a method. Java is *always* dynamic dispatch. That means that if some code has gotten a hold of an instance of this class (Created with `new Abc()`), and that code is **not** in this package, that they can *still* invoke this method.

Let's see it in action:

```
package abc;

class Abc {
    @Override public String toString() { return "Hello"; }
}

public class AbcMaker {
    public Object make() { return new Abc(); }
}
```

Note that here `AbcMaker` is public and `make()` can be invoked just fine from outside code; they know what Object is, and Abc is an Object. This lets code from outside the `abc` package invoke and obtain Abc instances, even though `Abc` is package private. This is fine.

They can then do:

```
package someOtherPackage;

class Test {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(new AbcMaker().make().toString());
    }
}
```

And that would print `Hello`, as expected - **that ends up invoking the toString defined in your package private class, invoked from outside the package!**

Thus, we come to a crucial conclusion:

**That `toString()` method in your package private class is ENTIRELY PUBLIC.**

It just is. You can't override a method and make it less accessible than it is in your parent type, because java is covariant, meaning any X is a valid standin for Y, if X is declared as `X extends Y`. if Y has public toString, then X's can't take that away, as all Xs must be valid Ys (and Ys have public toString methods, therefore Xs must also have this).

Thus, the compiler is forcing you here. The banal reason is 'cuz the spec says so', but the reason the spec says this is to make sure you, the programmer, are not confused, and that what you type and write matches with reality: That method *is* public, it has to be, so the compiler will refuse to continue unless you are on the same page as it and also say so.